# What is the methodology so that a GUI and its Widgets can adapt to any screen resolution?

Tags: tkinter, widget

This time I want to ask you if you know or have information about how I can automatically adjust a GUI and its Widgets to any screen resolution while keeping the distributions and sizes scaled according to each resolution.

I want to implement this methodology in tkinter.

Comment: just use `grid` or `pack` (or both on different containers), you also need to provide a [mre]